# Rails Rollback Transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions, rollback

I have problems with my Rails Block. After I implemented a comment-section I am not able to create posts anymore. The console gives me a rollback transaction. So I did

```
p = Post.new
p.valid? # false
p.errors.messages
```

It seems I have some validation problems with user `:user=>["must exist"]`. But before I implemented comments it did work. Can someone help me out?

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
  validates :body, presence: true


  has_attached_file :image  #, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**Post-migrate**

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
     create_table :posts do |t|
     t.string :title
     t.text :body

     t.timestamps
     end
   end
 end
```

**Post_controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :theme)
  end
end
```

Comment: Since you're using Rails 5, `belongs_to` associations are required by default. So when you're creating a post, you'll need to make sure you provide a user as well.

Comment: maybe i should have said that i am using active_admin and devise as well. so because it did work before. i thought i am providing a user

Comment: Does the error happen in your `PostsController`? If so, can you share the code you have?

Comment: how am i able to see where the errror occures? i dont think its in my posts_controller because of Active_admin using its own controller, isnt it? Post_controller is above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating a post you need to assign a user to that post in the create method under your posts controller. You could try something like this.

```
def create
  if current_user
    @post.user_id = current_user.id
  end

  ## More create method stuff
end
```

By default, in a `belongs_to` association a user is required to create the post otherwise you will not be able to create the post. Since, from the looks of it, you do not have anything that assigns the user to that post in the create method.

Comment: i tried it with your if statement, but nothing changed. has it sth to do with active admin?

Comment: Try adding `optional: true` after the `belongs_to` association. `belongs_to :user, optional: true`

Comment: `optional: true` fixed it. thank you alot. Just for understanding what is`optional: true` doing?

Comment: @minennick `optional: true` is telling the model of the association that, in this case, the post does not need a user to be created. It is set to `false` by default so if you do not provide a user to that post you will get the `rollback` error when creating a user in the terminal.

Comment: well that makes sense. Thanks again